# Nginx and Django/Wagtail : Origin checking failed - null does not match any trusted origins

Tags: django, nginx, wagtail

When i try to log on my admin page in wagtail, i get this error.

My settings.py has this line :
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = `["http://localhost","http://domain","http://server_ip","https://localhost","https://domain","https://server_ip"]`
Where `server_ip` is my ip and `domain` is my domain.

However the error message might to be dealing with nginx : the origin is not present in the request as django finds `null` as origin.
I have a reverse_proxy set in nginx as follows:

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

What can I add so django finds a correct origin?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here : it needs a special configuration of nginx
https://github.com/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx/issues/817

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                add_header P3P 'CP=""';
        }
```